# Classified contour-line visualization in SLD Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, style, sld

I have a problem with the Styling for the contour-lines. here is how I want to style them:

1. 4 different classes with different display zoom `MaxScaleDenominator`.
2. The interval is a variable (not fixed) based on user what to choose.
3. most important is **Rule number 4** that shows all the contour-lines with the elevation higher than 500, but the most important part is, I don't want to show all bands(all lines) just each 5 band.(leads us to render fewer lines on the map, that is why I used the `IEEERemainder`).

But simply it doesn't work with the tag `PropertyIsGreaterThan` but it works with the `PropertyIsEqualTo` tag, but this tag problem is, doesn't work with interval ex. `43`.

Is there any solution to fix it or another approach for my purpose?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>CL</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>CL</Title>
            <Abstract>CL</Abstract>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>rule 1</Name>
                    <Title>CL (all)</Title>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>40000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#006600</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>rule 2</Name>
                    <Title>CL (50)</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:And>
                            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                                <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
                                    <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
                                        <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                    <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">
                                        <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
                                    </ogc:Function>
                                </ogc:Function>
                                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                    <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                    <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                        </ogc:And>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>120000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#8600b3</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>rule 3</Name>
                    <Title>CL (200)</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                            <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
                                <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Function>
                                <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">
                                    <ogc:Literal>200.0</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </ogc:Function>
                            <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>200</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:LowerBoundary>
                            <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                                <ogc:Literal>500</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:UpperBoundary>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>150000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#3366ff</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>Rule 4</Name>
                    <Title>CL (500)</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                            <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
                                <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
                                    <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Function>
                                <ogc:Function name="parseDouble">
                                    <ogc:Literal>500.0</ogc:Literal>
                                </ogc:Function>
                            </ogc:Function>
                            <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <LineSymbolizer>
                        <Stroke>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</CssParameter>
                            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                        </Stroke>
                    </LineSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filter is not working the way you think it does.

You are trying to limit the number of contours drawn which is normally done by applying a filter that is equivalent to `value%x==0` where `x` is the "space" between contours.

But you are using values of `x` that are much too large to get any results (especially when combined with the other parts of your filter).

Here is an example with some of my data:

[image]

Unfiltered contours every 10m

[image]

Every other contour (i.e. 20m contours)

Using:

```
    <Rule>
      <Name>Rule 4</Name>
      <Title>CL (500)</Title>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
            <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
              <ogc:PropertyName>propertyVa</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>20.0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter> 
      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff0000</CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
```

and now every 50m

[image]

with this filter:

```
     <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:Function name="IEEERemainder">
            <ogc:Function name="int2ddouble">
              <ogc:PropertyName>propertyVa</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:Function>
          <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
```

Comment: you are absolutely right,if you change each time the `<ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>`, but problem is , I have one SLD file in GeoServer and the intervals is chosen by the user. Now how should I handle if the user choose the `57` as an interval.

Comment: you need to look at variables - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html